Movie about a group of guys cleaning out a mental asylum
I am trying to remember a movie we watched within the last ten years. I'm sure it was a thriller, but I can not remember if it had a supernatural aspect to it.
The movie stars a group of gentlemen who have to clean up a giant, abandoned mental asylum. I remember there being a kid, but it more likely would have been that one of the cleaners was considerably younger than the rest.
Everything starts out good, but over the course of cleaning the asylum, they each find curiosities that ultimately lead them to their individual downfalls. One particular cleaner is greedy, for example, and finds a cavity in a wall filled with money and small valuables. He is compelled to dig further into the cavity, until he eventually gets trapped, and realises he has dug his way into the crematorium.
The main character finds a group of recordings left by one of the patients. As he plays each recording, it tells the story behind this patient. Through most of them, the patient appears to be innocent, but the last recording reveals that they were admitted after killing their entire family. The movie ends with the sudden realisation that the main character has followed suite, and murdered his whole family off-screen.
I remember watching this movie in the last ten years, but I think it could have been from as far back as the mid 90s. It was definetly set in the US, and was in colour; does anyone have any idea what this movie may have been?

Possibly Session 9, a horror/mystery movie from 2001. It stars David Caruso.
Plot synopsis:

An asbestos abatement crew wins the bid for an abandoned insane asylum. What should be a straightforward, if rather rushed, job, is complicated by the personal histories of the crew. In particular, Hank is dating Phil's old girlfriend, and Gordon's new baby seems to be unnerving him more than should be expected. Things get more complicated as would-be lawyer Mike plays the tapes from a former patient with multiple personalities, including the mysterious Simon who does not appear until Session 9, and as Hank disappears after finding some old coins.

From wikipedia:

In the tunnels beneath the property, Hank finds a cache of antique Morgan dollar coins and other silver items, scattered from the crematory nearby.
Gordon finally breaks down and realizes he has killed his family and all his friends.

Trailer:



